# converting a bitset array to array of ints

Tags: c++, arrays, bitset

How would I change an array of bit sets to a 1d array of ints with each element holding only 1 digit in C++. for example, i have bitset<8> bitArray[n], and I want to bit into int binArray[8*n], where binArray holds something like [0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[0] and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`std::bitset::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at) to access the specifit bit. Keep in mind though, that `[0]` means the least significant bit, but we want to store them in the most significant -> least significant order, so we have to use the `7 - j` instead of simply `j`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    constexpr int SIZE = 5;
    std::bitset<8> bitArray[SIZE] = {3, 8, 125, 40, 13};
    int binArray[8 * SIZE];

    for(int i = 0, index = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j){
            binArray[index++] = bitArray[i][7 - j];
        }
    }
}
```

The `binArray`s content looks like so (*newlines added by me to improve readability*):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply construct an array:

```
std::array<int, 8*n> binArray;
size_t out = 0;
for (const auto& bits : bitArray)
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < n; ++ii)
        binArray[out++] = bitArray[ii];
```